# Ajax or jquery enabled Tab Zone Webpart with SourceCode

Tags: 2007, web-part, development, jquery, ajax

I am trying to find a TabZone Webpart Ajax enabled or using jQuery so that when I click on tab 2 while i am on tab 1 it shouldn't do a postback and make changes without loading page again.

We are currently using tab zone webpart but its not integrated with jquery or AJAX.

One most important thing is, each tab is opening a new site and I am using SharePoint 2007

[I find this link but there is no source code and am not sure if it will work either](http://www.sharepointfix.com/2009/02/ajaxify-zone-tabs-web-part-in.html)

So I would like to hear from people who actually used it and it definitely works :).

Code I am currently using for webpart can be find here,

[My Webpart without Ajax or jquery integration](http://read.pudn.com/downloads189/sourcecode/others/889130/EasyTabParts/TabList.cs__.htm)

I just came to know, we have two tabbed zone webpart , one is for webparts and one is for site,

I can cover the webparts one, e.g. displaying webparts on different tabs by using ajax but for tab zone with sites

> the site sabs however need to do a full page refresh to ensure
>   permissions are correctly applied

**I wonder what are possible options I can work on to make this problem overcome.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this a few times and I must say it works perfectly.

The author explains in extremely good detail how to implement this.

The essence of the blogs is:

- Download and install the AJAX extension
- Run the STSADM commands as shown in the blog
- Insert the `<asp:ScriptManager />` + add the additional javascript in the masterpage as shown in the blog
- Wrap the webpartzone which will contain the EasyTabWebpart in a `<asp:UpdatePanel />`

And that's pretty much it. It works perfectly.
The updatepanel makes sure that only that part of the page is updated, and only controls within the updatepanel trigger the asyncpostback.

Comment: +1 & I edited my question, please have a look again :) cheers

Comment: @TimeToThine I'm not sure I follow? You want to do the same with sites diplayed in the EasyTabWebpart?

Comment: what actually happens is, when i click on a tab, it postbacks and opens another site/page and also checks for permissions of user while loading